# Counting and Reading integers from a file

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, counting

Okay, so at the moment I am having a hard time trying to read integers from a file. ( I am using C++)

```
    int main(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    string name;
    string line;
    while(getline(cin,line)) //get the line from input//
    {
        size++;
    }
    cout << size;
}
```

This is the code at the moment and the input from a file is

```
2 3 17 1 9 23 8 4 22 15 10
```

`8 7 14`

I use visual studio 2010 and have set up the debugger to take input in from a file and output to another file.

Output is just 2 because it is counting lines only.

In any case, what I am trying to do is count all the numbers in this file and then create an array of "size" counted and then input each number into the array. Now the reason i want it this way is because I want to be able to take in any number of integers. Can someone please help me here?

I want this to work without using vectors.

Comment: What is the current output of the program?

Comment: @DanPichelman The current output right now is 2 because all it is doing is counting the number of Lines and not the individual integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::ifstream in("myFile.txt");
int i, size=0;
while(in>>i) // counting int at the input
{
    size++;
}
in.seekg (0, in.beg);
int arr=new int[size];
for(size_t i=0;i<size;++i)
  in>>arr[i];

...
delete[]arr;
```

Why not with vector?

```
std::ifstream in("myFile.txt");
int i;
std::vector<int> v;
while(in>>i) // counting int at the input
{
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: This is good, however, It doesn't allow me to creak arr using the new method as it cannot change "int into int*"

Comment: What do you mean with "change int into int*" ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: here is the c++ your looking for

my c++ skills are a little rusty so please forgive, however this should work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
#define MAX_LINES 25
#define MAX_IN_LINE 50

int main() {
  //open our file
  ifstream myfile ("test.txt");
  //initialize our array's
  int myarray[MAX_LINES][MAX_IN_LINE];
  //used for knowing how many numbers are stored in each array
  int totalargs[MAX_LINES];
  //rest of variables
  string line,tempnum;
  int end=0;
  int firstarg=0,secondarg=0;
  int num;

  //set all of our arrays to be zero'd out
  memset(myarray,0,MAX_LINES*MAX_IN_LINE);
  memset(totalargs,0,MAX_LINES);

  //make sure file is opened
  if (myfile.is_open()) {
    //get a line
    getline(myfile,line);
    //the first line is the number, so set it to num
    num=atoi(line.c_str());

    while(!myfile.eof()) {
      getline(myfile,line);
      //if there is a , in the line we have gotten
      while((end=line.find(' ',0))!=string::npos) {
        //get the number before the ,
        tempnum=line.substr(0,end);
        myarray[firstarg][secondarg]=atoi(tempnum.c_str());
        secondarg++;
        //erase the part of the line we have gotten
        line.erase(0,end+1);
      }
      //we will have an extra number at the end after that loop
      //this gets that last number
      tempnum=line.substr(0,line.length());
      myarray[firstarg][secondarg]=atoi(tempnum.c_str());
      //set the number of args to our array
      totalargs[firstarg]=secondarg;
      firstarg++;
      //reset arg.
      secondarg=0;
    }
  } else {
    cout << "cannot open";
  }

  //this is extra, but it just shows you your variables and that
  //they really do have numbers in them.
  cout << "num: " << num << endl;
  for (int x=0;x<firstarg;x++) {
    cout << "Array " << x+1 << ": " << myarray[x][0];
    for (int y=1;y<=totalargs[x];y++) {
      cout << "," << myarray[x][y];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

another much more simpler solution is

```
vector<int> numbers;
ifstream fin("infile.txt");
int x;
while( fin >> x ) {
    numbers.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look much like C++ to me. Is this C#?

Comment: @Dukeling I am using C++, though it may not look like it.

Comment: @MagicalToast I know your question is, but is this answer?

Comment: @Dukeling Well It is sort of, however I want to beable to do it without vectors or var.

Comment: @PrakashChennupati I'm using C++ so this wouldn't exactly work... I edited the question saying C++, I'm sorry for any confusion

Comment: ya sorry, i didnt see it intially. I posted a c++ version with more detail

Comment: @PrakashChennupati Thank you, I'm going take take a look at it here